# How to use NULL-safe equal to mysql operator with idiorm & paris

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to make this request with the idiorm & paris database toolkit (http://j4mie.github.io/idiormandparis/):

```
SELECT mqtt_table.* FROM `shelf_mqtt_confirmation_message` `mqtt_table` WHERE NOT( `confirm_result` <=> 'positive')
```

I have tried to do:

```
$orm->where_not_equal("confirm_result","positive");
```

But this is equivalent to:

```
SELECT mqtt_table.* FROM `shelf_mqtt_confirmation_message` `mqtt_table` WHERE NOT( `confirm_result` = 'positive')
```

Which excludes all the cases where `confirm_result` is NULL: but I also want to keep these rows. The problem is that in MySQL  = comparison operator returns NULL if one of the elements to compare is NULL instead of returning 0. ( When <=> performs an equality comparison like the = operator, but returns 1 rather than NULL if both operands are NULL, and 0 rather than NULL if one operand is NULL)

So my question is, does the operator  <=> exist in idiorm & paris? Are there some solutions to do the request I would like to do else than by using brutal methods as raw_query or where_raw?

Comment: @scaisEdge Thing means `FROM xyz as abc` did not know that works with bacjticks too.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions   . thanks  ..  i understood ..

Comment: `expression IS NOT NULL` is this what you want? Did your ORM not have something like `$orm->where_is_not_null("confirm_result");`?

Comment: no in fact  i would like to do : `SELECT mqtt_table.* FROM `shelf_mqtt_confirmation_message` `mqtt_table` WHERE (NOT( `confirm_result` = 'positive') OR `confirm_result` IS NULL)

Comment: in fact my problem is that the comparison operator = return NULL if one of the element is NULL.

Comment: Sry, dont know your ORM and you dont create the sql by yourself, so can not help more here. And so my fist comment can also be without `NOT` `$orm->where_is_null("confirm_result")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the [`where_raw()`<sup>docs link</sup>](http://idiorm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying.html#raw-where-clauses) method.

The following SQL query can be rewritten

```
SELECT *
  FROM shelf_mqtt_confirmation_message
 WHERE NOT(confirm_result <=> 'positive')
```

with Idiorm in the following code

```
$messages = ORM::for_table('shelf_mqtt_confirmation_message')
    ->where_raw('NOT(confirm_result <=> ?)', array('positive'))
    ->find_many();
```

in [Paris<sup>docs link</sup>](http://paris.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying.html#querying) it could be something like

```
$messages = ShelfMqttConfMessage::where_raw(
        'NOT(confirm_result <=> ?)', array('positive')
    )
    ->find_many();
```

or if you're using the model factory instead

```
$messages = Model::factory('ShelfMqttConfMessage')
    ->where_raw('NOT(confirm_result <=> ?)', array('positive'))
    ->find_many();
```